# How to loop through visible form fields but do something when a certain field is met in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is it possible to stop at a certain form field when you looping through the visible form fields in form's `__init__`?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for visible in self.visible_fields():
        if visible == "field_name": #<---?
             #do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the [**`.name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.name) of the visible field, so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for visible in self.visible_fields():
        if visible.name == 'field_name':
             # do something …
```